# p vs V graph - dependence question

Tags: thermodynamics, work, ideal-gas

**Context:**
I'm reading Fermi's *Thermodynamics*. On page 6, he states that the work done transforming a system from state $A$ to state $B$ (with the accompanying graph below) is given by $$W=\int_{V_A}^{V_B}p\text{ } dV.$$

*$\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$[image: p-v graph]*

**Question:** In the graph, is $p$ dependent on $V$? If so, how and why? I can't make sense of it intuitively. Is the book already assuming the *Ideal Gas Law?*

Comment: $p$ might depend on $V$, yes. I believe this graph just shows a possible relationship. The formula is general and will work for any relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by @FGSUZ is correct. I just want to add a few minor points.

Pressure $p$ depends on $V$, but not only on $V$. You may choose the other thermodynamic variable to be for example temperature $T$ (any choice different from $V$ will do), and then the dependence is written $p(V,T)$. In a thermodynamic process going from state 1 to state 2, $V$ and $T$ are continuously varied. This process forms a three-dimensional curve in the $p$-$V$-$T$ diagram. What is presented in Fermi's graph is the projection of this three-dimensional curve on the $p$-$V$ plane. To calculate work this is all we need. See that no assumption was made regarding the thermodynamic process except that it is quasistatic which enables us to represent the process by a continuous curve; in particular, ideal gas behavior was not assumed.

Comment: It makes more sense now, looking at it as a projection! And I am assuming the dependence $p(V,T)$ is derived from the state equation.

Comment: @yahya $p(V,T)$ is itself a state equation. You may benefit by reading Thermodynamics by Callen.

Comment: Fermi defines the state equation to be $f(p, V, T)=0$; what I meant is, when you rearrange this equation to have every $V$ and $T$ term on one side, and properly scale, you get a relation that's something like $p=$(terms of V and T). I can then rewrite the relation on the right as $p(V,T)$. (edit: laTeX fix)

Comment: @yahya You are right.

Answer (score 3):

This is only **an example**. In this case, the pressure does depend on $V$, as you can directly see on the graph. If it didn't depend on V, all volumes would have the same value of $P$, that is, $P$ would be a horizontal line.

In general, $P$ depends on $V$, and the shape depends on the problem you have.

For the concrete case of an ideal gas, at constant temperature, $P\cdot V=const$, so it means that $P=\frac{const}{V}$ and it looks like the $1/x$ function.

Comment: "If it didn't depend on V, all volumes would have the same value of P, that is, P would be a horizontal line." I'd argue that you wouldn't be able to graph it like this at all.  The graph implies a relationship between P and V; so making a 2D graph of any form gives a dependence between the two.

Comment: A horizontal line is a particular case of a straight line. In an isobaric process, pressure is constant, and so it does not depend on V, since it's the same value, no matter what V is.